# Pandas DataFrame.apply on an empty dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Consider a trivial example:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(dict(A=[1,2],B=[11,22]))
df
A   B
0   1   11
1   2   22
df["C"] = df.apply(lambda row: row["A"]+1, axis=1)
df
A   B   C
0   1   11  2
1   2   22  3
```

So far so good, but what if a dataframe is empty:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=["A","B"])
df

A   B
```

Suddenly .apply raises:

```
df["C"] = df.apply(lambda row: row["A"]+1, axis=1)
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _set_item_mgr(self, key, value)
   3750         try:
-> 3751             loc = self._info_axis.get_loc(key)
   3752         except KeyError:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3362             except KeyError as err:
-> 3363                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3364 

KeyError: 'C'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_21916/2953292978.py in <module>
----> 1 df["C"] = df.apply(lambda row: row["A"]+1, axis=1)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
   3600             self._setitem_array(key, value)
   3601         elif isinstance(value, DataFrame):
-> 3602             self._set_item_frame_value(key, value)
   3603         elif (
   3604             is_list_like(value)
```

Is this some kind of a known feature or a defect in pandas core code?

Comment: Which pandas version are you using? `df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["A","B"]) ; df["C"] = df.apply(lambda row: row["A"]+1, axis=1)` works fine in pandas 2.2

Comment: I am using '1.3.4', so it seems that indeed 2.2 fixes my issue. Many thanks!